# Mark as "Do Not Back up"

Tags: ios, icloud

I have a somewhat large database shipping with my application that is ONLY readable (the user writes nothing to this database). I'm looking for a very simple way to make sure that this database is not backed up. Is there an easy way to mark the database file as "do not back this up"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `NSURL` instance with your file, and then set the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` resource value:

```
[url setResourceValue:@YES forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:NULL]; // Can use an NSError for error reporting of course
```

From [QA 1719](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)

Comment: I had to actually put: `[dbUrl setResourceValue:@YES forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];` with `error` defined as `NSError *error __autoreleasing =NULL;` but then it compiled. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, the formatting in the QA doesn't make the code too readable. I've updated my answer.